# ios app validation error : Invalid BundleOS TypeCode - Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, validating

I created a provisioning profile for distribution on apple developpers and create my app page on itunes connect linked to this profile. The app is running properly.

Now, I am trying to submit my app to the app store but I got an error when I want to upload my app : "Invalid BundleOS TypeCode. Could not find a [CFBundlePackageType] in your application bundle's Info.plist file must be one of [APPL]". 
(I create an archive, validate, export and try to upload and got this).

I think it's coming from a framework, called AlamoFire, in my project. I add week ago in the project and add it to "Link binary with libraries". It has its own workspace and project,in my project : 
[image: project architecture]
 - 
[image: architecture of framework]
.

To get that error message when I want to upload my app, I already change the bundle identifier in the framework project and change the version in "General" to match my project. I don't know if that's was right... (i got a problem when I wanted to upload my app with the bundle identifier - not suitable records were found - and a problem because version string was too long).

I don't know what to change and where... What should I do ?

---

Edit : Just changed my app BundleTypeCode in .plist from BNDL to APPL and it worked without changing my framework.

Answer (score 0):

Version string too long: look at your version string, at the general project info. Try naming it 1.0.0. Then, if that passes the validation, change the naming to something similar to this.
No suitable records: check your bundle id. Did you create the app with that bundle id? Itunes connect asks you to select the Developer section app you want to create a project for. It looks like you didn't create the app that way or you changed the bundle id later on.

Comment: I checked everything and my bundle iD on appple developper, itunes connect and my project are the same. 
I got the same  error message :-/ 
What should the Bundle Os Type Code should be in the framework Info.plist ? Now it's set to FMWK.